# For Loop in R not printing what I need

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

In R, I would like elements in list1 to be added to list2

```
list1 = c(1,2,3,4)
list2 = c(2,4,6,8)

for(i in list1){
  for(j in list2){
    print(i + j)
  }
}
```

I am looking for the loop to return

```
3
6
9
12
```

but it returns

```
3
5
7
4
6
8
5
7
9
```

how can I get it to return the first former case?

Comment: if you want a vector containing `list1` and `list2`, use `list3=c(list1,list2)`. If you want to add them, `list3=list1+list2`

Comment: `for(i in 1:length(list1)){
  print(list1[i] + list2[i])
}` or `mapply(function(x, y) x+y, list1, list2)` or, even better, simply `list1 + list2`

Comment: The comment by boski will resolve your issues. But I would suggest trying to understand why you get the result you do. See that you set i, and execute everything inside of this, which is another loop where j increments, so it will execute for each element of j (list2). then i will increment and execute again, with the second i value of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using for loop we need to mention jth interation equals to i.

```
for(i in list1){
  for(j in list2[list1==i]){
    print(i + j)
  }
}
[1] 3
[1] 6
[1] 9
[1] 12
```

Comment: hi could you explain what `list2[list1 == 1]` does?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic question and duplicate of many other questions.

Each for loop iterates over the iterator. The comments answer you question but for understanding below is an example that will show you 'why' this is happening:

```
list1 = c(1,2,3,4)
list2 = c(2,4,6,8)
for(i in seq_along(list1)){
  for(j in seq_along(list2)){
    cat("list1[[", i,"]] + list2[[", j,"]] =",list1[[i]],"+",list2[[j]],"=", list1[[i]] + list2[[j]],"\n")
  }
}
```

This should illustrate how the for loop works.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

list1 = c(1,2,3,4)
list2 = c(2,4,6,8)

purrr::walk2(list1, list2, ~print(.x + .y))
[1] 3
[1] 6
[1] 9
[1] 12
```

`list1` is the `.x` and `list2` is the `.y`